# Iterate through a formArray containing inside other model values

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-forms, formarray

I have question how can i iterate through formArray and use inside data from other array. I added example below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-reactive-form-test',
  styleUrls: ['./reactive-form-test.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="questionForm">
      <ng-container formArrayName="questions">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let question of questionControls.controls; let i = index">
<input type="text" [formGroupName]="i">
            {{?????? how to display prop1}}
            {{?????? how to display prop2}}
      </ng-container>
      
</ng-container>
    </form>
  `
})
export class ReactiveFormTestComponent implements OnInit {
  questionForm: FormGroup;

  questions: ModelClass[];
  get questionControls() {
     return this.questionForm.get('questions') as FormArray;
  }
  

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.questionForm = this.fb.group({
      questions: this.fb.array([])
    });
    this.questions = [];
    this.questions.push(new ModelClass(1, 1, 1, 1));
    this.questions.push(new ModelClass(2, 3, 1, 2));
    this.questions.push(new ModelClass(3, 4, 1, 3));
    this.questions.forEach(value => {
      const control = this.questionForm.get('questions') as FormArray;
      control.push(this.fb.group({
        id: [value.id],
        prop1: [value.prop1]
      }));
    });
  }
}

export class ModelClass {
id,
prop1,
prop2,
prop3
}
```

And my question is how can i dispaly inside formArray loop data rom model (questions) - prop2, prop3 ??

Comment: You should move the line 'const control = this.questionForm.get('questions') as FormArray;' to outside of the foreach. I also think it's bad practice to loop over the array for the purpose of printing something from another array. you should reconsider what your code needs to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
        <ng-container *ngFor="let question of questionControls.controls; let i= index">
            {{questions[i].prop1}}
            {{questions[i].prop2}}
            {{questions[i].prop3}}
        </ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the solution was really simple but I couldn't come on it :|